# What is the convolution here?

Tags: generating-functions, convolution

I'm reading Knuth/Graham/Patashnik's: *Concrete Mathematics*.

> [image]

- In here, it's not clear to me what is the convolution, is it the act of writing as this?

> [image]

- Is this convolution somehow related to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution)? I tried to read it but I couldn't go far.

Comment: "The **sequence** $\langle c_n\rangle$ defined by $(5.54)$ is called the **convolution**..."

Comment: @PedroTamaroff It was confusing because he gave a new name to something I was used to, the product of two series or polynomials. In the same reading, I also discovered this way of writing the product: 

$$a_0b_0+(a_0b_1+a_1b_0)x+(a_0b_2+a_1b_1+a_2b_0)x^2+\ldots$$

Which would help me a lot on evaluate the coefficient. I got confused because as that first thing had a name, perhaps he was wanting to call this way to write of convolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several related notions of convolution in mathematics. This one is the convolution of two sequences. Suppose that

$$A=\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle=\langle a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots\rangle$$

and

$$B=\langle b_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle=\langle b_0,b_1,b_2,\ldots\rangle$$

are two sequences of real or complex numbers. The *convolution* of $A$ and $B$ is a new sequence

$$C=\langle c_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle=\langle c_0,c_1,c_2,\ldots\rangle$$

defined as follows:

$$c_n=\sum_{k=0}^na_kb_{n-k}\;.$$

Thus,

$$C=\langle a_0b_0,a_0b_1+a_1b_0,a_0b_2+a_1b_1+a_2b_0,\ldots\rangle\;.$$

If we use $*$ to represent the operation of convolution, we have $C=A\mathop{*}B$.

Each of these sequences has an associated power series:

$$\begin{align*}
g_A(x)&=\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nx^n\tag{1}\\
g_B(x)&=\sum_{n\ge 0}b_nx^n\tag{2}\\
\end{align*}$$

The point of that passage in *Concrete Mathematics* is that if you multiply the summations $(1)$ and $(2)$ as if they were ordinary polynomials, you get the power series associated with $A\mathop{*}B$:

$$\begin{align*}
\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nx^n\right)\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}b_nx^n\right)&=(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\ldots)(b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2+\ldots)\\\\
&=a_0b_0+(a_0b_1+a_1b_0)x+(a_0b_2+a_1b_1+a_2b_0)x^2+\ldots\\\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(\sum_{k=0}^na_kb_{n-k}\right)x^n\;.
\end{align*}$$

The most relevant Wikipedia link is probably [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product), for the *Cauchy product* of series.

Comment: It was confusing because he gave a new name to something I was used to, the product of two series or polynomials. In the same reading, I also discovered this way of writing the product: 

$$a_0b_0+(a_0b_1+a_1b_0)x+(a_0b_2+a_1b_1+a_2b_0)x^2+\ldots$$

Which would help me a lot on evaluate the coefficients. I got confused because as that first thing had a name, perhaps he was wanting to call this way to write of convolution.

Comment: @Vÿska: The convolution is *related* to the product of the series, but it’s not the same thing. Here *convolution* refers to a binary operation on *sequences* (and to the sequence that is the result of that operation). One can talk about the convolution of two sequences without making any reference to series or polynomials at all.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but could you give one example of speaking about convolution without mentioning series of polynomials?

Comment: @Vÿska: ‘The convolution of the constant sequence $\langle 1,1,1,\ldots\rangle$ with a sequence $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is the sequence $$\left\langle\sum_{k=0}^na_k:n\in\Bbb N\right\rangle\;.’$$

Answer (score 1):

Given two sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$, we can form their convolution which is a new sequence $(c_n)$ given by $$c_n = \sum_{k=0}^na_kb_{n-k}.$$ This definition is such that the following formal manipulation of power series holds:

$$\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_nz^n\right) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nz^n.$$

The main concern in the linked article is the convolution of functions. The convolution that you're considering here is often referred to as discrete convolution as the [very same article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution) mentions.